# Linux Multicast Subsequent Socket Steals Data

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, boost, multicast

I am trying to use Boost ASIO UDP sockets to multicast data. I believe that I have functioning senders and receivers, as everything works as intended with a single sender and receiver. However, when we now have multiple receivers on the same machine, only the receiver that was bound to the address last will receive the data. I believe that this may be a configuration issue, but I will provide everything that I can.

**Network:**

```
[root@dev ~]# ifconfig
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:C1:34:B7  
          inet addr:192.168.6.131  Bcast:192.168.6.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fec1:34b7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:25060380 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24562809 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2030905679 (1.8 GiB)  TX bytes:5249474660 (4.8 GiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2687213321 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2687213321 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1633558802477 (1.4 TiB)  TX bytes:1633558802477 (1.4 TiB)
```

**Multicast Sender:**

```
MulticastSender(const std::string& listenaddress,
                const std::string& multicastaddress,
                const unsigned short port) : Address(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(listenaddress)),
                                             Port(port),
                                             Endpoint(Address, port),
                                             Socket(IOService, Endpoint.protocol()),
                                             Work(IOService) {
        Socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(multicastaddress).to_v4(), boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(listenaddress).to_v4()));
        auto self = this;
        WorkThread = std::thread([self]()
                                 {
                                     self->IOService.run();
                                 });

    }
```

**Multicast Receiver:**

```
MulticastReceiver(const std::string &listenaddress,
                  const std::string &multicastaddress,
                  const unsigned short port) : Socket(IOService),
                                               ListenAddress(listenaddress),
                                               MulticastAddress(multicastaddress),
                                               Work(IOService) {
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listenendpoint(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), port);
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    Socket.open(listenendpoint.protocol(), ec);
    Socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true), ec);
    Socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::enable_loopback(true), ec);
    Socket.bind(listenendpoint, ec);
    Socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(multicastaddress).to_v4(), boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(listenaddress).to_v4()), ec);
    auto self = this;
    WorkThread = std::thread([self]()
                             {
                                 self->IOService.run();
                             });
    Socket.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(Buffers[BufferIndex], MaxLength), Endpoint,
                              boost::bind(&MulticastReceiver::HandleReceiveFrom, this,
                                          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

For `listenaddress` I have tried both specifying the interface with `192.168.6.131` and I have also tried leaving it up to the system with `0.0.0.0`. I have also tried both variations of `join_group` where you either specify the interface or not.

When I have applications running, I am able to see the proper number of members in the proper address when I run netstat -gn.

**Here are my inputs to both the sender and receiver:**

```
listenaddress = "0.0.0.0"; // or listenaddress = "192.168.6.131"; // eth1
multicastaddress = "239.140.127.0";
port = 35000;
```

I am running this on `CentOS 6.6 with kernel Linux dev 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64` and running `Boost 1.55.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to figure out why the multicast was not working on that setup, but I was able to get the code to work elsewhere so I figured that I might as well post the changes for the sender and receiver.

**Multicast Sender:**

```
MulticastSender(const std::string& multicastaddress,
                const unsigned short port) : Port(port),
                                             Endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(multicastaddress), port),
                                             Socket(IOService, Endpoint.protocol()),
                                             Work(IOService) {
    auto self = this;
    WorkThread = std::thread([self]()
                             {
                                 self->IOService.run();
                             });

    std::string data = "Test message";
    Socket.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(data), Endpoint, boost::bind(&MulticastSender::SendHandler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

**Multicast Receiver:**

```
MulticastReceiver(const std::string &listenaddress,
                  const std::string &multicastaddress,
                  const unsigned short port,
                  const int numbuffers) : Socket(IOService),
                                          ListenAddress(listenaddress),
                                          MulticastAddress(multicastaddress),
                                          Work(IOService) {
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listenendpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(listenaddress), port);
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    Socket.open(listenendpoint.protocol(), ec);
    Socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true), ec);
    Socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::enable_loopback(true), ec);
    Socket.bind(listenendpoint, ec);
    Socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(multicastaddress)), ec);
    auto self = this;
    WorkThread = std::thread([self]()
                             {
                                 self->IOService.run();
                             });
    Socket.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(Buffers[BufferIndex], MaxLength), Endpoint,
                              boost::bind(&MulticastReceiver::HandleReceiveFrom, this,
                                          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```